# DB backup with table entries.

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to backup a DB, I've Google and found code that appears to work, but it ony backs up the DB structure and not the entries in the DB.

There are no errors reported, and also how do you export as CSV format the table?

*code for backup a DB:*

```
public void BackupDB() {
 InputStream myInput;

    try {

        myInput = new FileInputStream("/data/data/com.cecchina.mathew.lessonsDB/databases/Teaching");
        // Set the output folder on the SDcard
        File directory = new File("/mnt/sdcard/external_sd/TeachingBKup/");
        // Create the folder if it doesn't exist:
        if (!directory.exists()) 
        {
            directory.mkdirs();
        } 
        // Set the output file stream up:

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(directory.getPath()+ "/Teaching.backup");
        // Transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0)
        {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        // Close and clear the streams
        myOutput.flush();

        myOutput.close();

        myInput.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
Toast.makeText(ourContext, "Backup Unsuccesfull file not found error!",          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
Toast.makeText(ourContext, "Backup Unsuccesfull IO error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
Toast.makeText(ourContext, "DataBase structure backed up!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Suggest me where I am lacking?

Comment: What makes you think it only backs up the structure?  You copied the file, so everythign is there.

Comment: Oh, BTW, welcome to SO.  If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the backup before you have inserted any data, of course all you get is the structure (as you put it).

Your code copies a complete file, so if there is data in the database, it is getting copied to the card.

I use pretty much the same code (launched from a menu item) to perform backups in several of my apps.  I also have code to restore/import, and when I do all my data is there.

Comment: Hmm confused here. My DB on the S2 is 20k when empty and circa 20484k when it has 25 entries, but when I run the backup its always 20k...

Comment: O.K just had another look at the generated backup, using cat on the file it shows data within the file. Just having a bad day... Thanks for the replies :)

Comment: Oh forgot, Barak how do I import the backup, at least that way I can be sure it works. Many thanks

Comment: Just make a method the same as your backup, but exchange the path and file names for the two streams.  Maybe rename the old DB so you have a backup until you are sure it is working properly.  If my answer has helped.you, Accepted answers and upvotes are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Barak, it works  very well now. Do you happen to know how to export the DB table is CSV format...